# Is it possible to take a screenshot of currently displayed window programmatically if my app is running in the background without ROOT?

Tags: android, screenshot, floating-action-button

**What I want to do:**

1.Launch the application developed by myself.

2.Then the application will launch another designated app by clicking a certain button.

3.My application then keeps running in the background and only display a small floating window above all other windows.

4.By clicking the small floating window, my application will take a screenshot (programmatically) of the currently displayed window and save it to the external storage.

**I've Googled around the internet, and found similar questions like this:**

[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android#)

**Anyone knows if it's possible to do this kind of thing without Root privilege or if so how?**

**ADD:**
I may asked my question in the wrong way, actually I just want to know if it's possible to take a screenshot of the currently displayed window when my app is running in the background.

Comment: please specify what you **don't know**

Comment: @Pan. link specified by you in question doesn't ask for root access from user. It will work normally like any other app. Permission asked from user for root access is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />`.

Comment: @vipul_asri I think I may ask my question in the wrong way. Actually I want to know if it's possible to take a screenshot of the currently displayed window when my app is running in the background with no root privilege.

Comment: @Pan. yes you can do that procedure for taking screenshot programmatically is described above in link and for floating button checkout this library : [FloatingView](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView)

Comment: @vipul_asri I'll have a deeper look, thanks!